# How to use regsub to grab values after a pattern tcl?

Tags: tcl

If I have a variable that has values like this:

```
set var "/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr"
```

How do I use regsub so that it removes everything except the second last value "mno"?

Comment: Whether the constraint to match the pattern is based on the string `mno` or the second last element having the `/` as a delimiter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this:

```
set updatedValue [regsub {^.*(mno).*$} $value {\1}]
```

which is an old trick from the Unix utility, sed, translated into Tcl. That will remove everything but the last text to match `mno`. Pick your RE appropriately.

And don't use this for manipulating filenames, please. It might work, but it makes your code more confusing. The `file` command has utility subcommands for this sort of work and they handle tricky gotchas that you might not be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Why a regular expression?
How about:

```
set val [file tail [file dirname $var]]
```

References: [file](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
% regexp {.*/([^/]+)/} $var -> val
1
% set val
mno
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Using `split` and `lindex`

```
% set var "/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr"
/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr
% 
% puts "[lindex [split $var "/"] end-1]"
mno
```